# Linker error in QT Creator (C++)

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I've been trying on and off for quite a while to do the CS106B Stanford course on C++. My latest attempt has been with Qt Creator, the IDE they recently switched to in order to make things simpler. Unfortunately, I've been having just as many issues with this IDE as VS and XCode. My two errors:

`1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64`

`linker command failed with exit code 1`

None of the other questions I've seen on stackoverflow about this issue has been helpful, I think it may have to do with running a 32bit library on clang 64 bit?

I'm running Mac OSX Yosemite, with the sample-qtcreator-project.pro taken from http://stanford.edu/~stepp/cppdoc/

Thanks for any and all suggestions. I'm using Qt Creator 5.3.2

My code:
quadratic.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include "console.h"
#include "quadratic.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double a, b, c, r1, r2;
    getCoefficients(a, b, c);
    solveQuadratic(a, b, c, r1, r2);
    printRoots(r1, r2);
    return 0;

}

void getCoefficients(double &a, double &b, double &c) {
    cout << "Enter coefficients for the quadratic equation: " << endl;
    cout << "a: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "b: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "c: ";
    cin >> c;
}

void solveQuadratic(double a, double b, double c, double &x1, double &x2) {
    if (a == 0) error("The coefficient 'a' must be nonzero.");
    double disc = b*b - 4 * a * c;
    if (disc < 0) error("This equation has no real roots.");
    double sqrtDisc = sqrt(disc);
    x1 = (-b + sqrtDisc) / (2 * a);
    x2 = (-b - sqrtDisc) / (2 * a);

}

void printRoots(double x1, double x2) {
    if (x1 == x2) {
        cout << "There is a double root at " << x1 << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "The roots are " << x1 << " and " << x2 << endl;
    }
}

void error(string msg) {
    cerr << msg << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

and finally, quadratic.h

```
void getCoefficients(double & a, double & b, double & c);
void solveQuadratic(double a, double b, double c, double & x1, double & x2);
void printRoots(double x1, double x2);
void error(std::string msg);
```

Additional compiler output:

duplicate symbol __Z5errorNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE in:
    error.o
    quadratic.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [simple-project.app/Contents/MacOS/simple-project] Error 1
15:54:50: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project simple-project (kit: Desktop Qt 5.3 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"

Comment: I can run the project smoothly and I am on Mac OSX Yosemite. But surprisingly I have faced similar problems previously, mainly due to llvm. Simply check whether you have constructor and destructors written perfectly.

Comment: I'm just trying to run the Quadratic.cpp program from early chapter 2, I'm not even using classes so there aren't any constructors/destructors in my program. What version of Qt Creator are you using?

Comment: sounds like you have duplicate code (perhaps code autogenerated when you create a new project, plus your own) - check especially for the `main()` function, creating a new project may have automatically given you one

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, I've already checked and there's only one instance of main()

Comment: The question shows the message about a duplicate symbol, but does not show the message that *names* that symbol.  Is it `main()` or are you assuming that?

Comment: someone suggested checking main(), i can't see any other repeated function. If you see my edit in the main question, i added some extra compiler information. it says duplicate symbol "blah blah blah" in error.o quadratic.o

Comment: It is complaining about a duplicate error(string) function.  We can see the one in quadratic.cpp, we can't see the one in error.cpp.  Use a namespace.

Comment: If i literally copy and paste the code into VS2012 it works just fine, error function and all.

Comment: @Asif, I am using 5.4 with clang